# why won't my parser print the string in my language [DEFUNCT]

Tags: python, compiler-construction

I don't know what to add. At the time that's why I only posted the code.
But the intended result is that a string should be parsed (and successfully printed).
I don't remember what the issue was, but by the sounds of it, it probably just didn't print.

(I'm doing this to get back on S.O.'s "good side".)

```py
class Lex:
    def run(args, string):
        if args == "print":
            print(str(string))
class Calin:
    string = ""
    running = ""
    def parse(args):
        lexic = Lex
        string = ""
        tok = ""
        state = 0
        for char in args:
            tok += char
            if tok == " ":
                if state == 0:
                    tok = ""
                elif state == 1:
                    tok = " "
            elif tok == "\"":
                if state == 0:
                    state = 1
                elif state == 1:
                    state = 0
            elif state == 1:
                string += char
            elif tok == "print":
                running = "print"
        lexic.run(running, string)
            
trans = Calin
trans.parse("print \"WOW A STRING\"")
```

Comment: sorry, I don't know the new format...

Comment: Why are you using classes? You never refer to `self`...

Comment: Please don't post questions that consist entirely of code, except for the title. Explain what your code is supposed to do and how, what happens instead (including any error messages you might get) and what you've gathered so far from debugging.

Comment: Note: You can use a debugger or even just add a `print` and see that `string` is empty. Hence `state == 1` is never true. Or to be more clear `tok == "\""` is never true.

Comment: @sepp2k as I said I don't know the new format, is there a way to switch it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are making `state == 1` only when `tok == "\""`, which never happens (You are keep adding `str`s to it.). Changing it to `char` works:

```
class Lex:
    def run(args, string):
        if args == "print":
            print(str(string))

class Calin:
    string = ""
    running = ""
    def parse(args):
        lexic = Lex
        string = ""
        tok = ""
        state = 0
        for char in args:
            tok += char
            if tok == " ":
                if state == 0:
                    tok = ""
                elif state == 1:
                    tok = " "
            elif char == "\"": # <<< Change this
                if state == 0:
                    state = 1
                elif state == 1:
                    state = 0
            elif state == 1:
                string += char
            elif tok == "print":
                running = "print"
        lexic.run(running, string)

trans = Calin
trans.parse("print \"WOW A STRING\"")
# WOW A STRING
```